# How to drag single row data from one datagrid to another? WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

I have 2 Datagrids on the same form. One of the Datagrids holds data e.g. Policy Number, name, date etc... and I want to be able to drag a single row of data, including all the cells in that row, on top of a user listed in another Datagrid which will then send all that data and the user to another table in an SQL database. (Basically assigning a Policy to a user).

I know how to create the table in SQL but I am unsure how to make the drag and drop work and how to get the data from both data grids collectively.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Te43s.png]

Answer (score 0):

Try to imagine your solution based on a series on events. My example is very basic, you will need to flesh it out.

```
DragLeave DataGridView1
```

Here you want to grab details of the row which has selected.

Then...

```
DragEnter DataGridView2
```

Here you want to use your SQL to perform an `INSERT` to the actual table, based on what has been dragged. If there are no errors, you probably also want to remove the *dragged* data from the first view.

---

Helpful References:

[Drag between DataGrids (Adapt From WinForms)](http://tv.devexpress.com/Content/XtraGrid/XtraGridDragRowsBetweenGrids/XtraGridDragRowsBetweenGrids.pdf)

[WPF Drag and Drop](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF)

---

Hint: I would change the `SelectionMode` of the first `DataGridView` to `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the reference. I will work through it now and will let you know soon if any problems occur.

Comment: Just been going through for the link you need to buy a product.